# Why can an entityManager be created without any default/implemented Entity Manager Factory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working an application which is using JPA and Hibernate.

But in my DAO(Data access objects) layer, I see the simple code to get the entitymanager object. that is

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mydatabase")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I am not interacting anything with entity manager factory.

**Why can an entityManager be created without any default/implemented Entity Manager Factory?**

My code doesn't specify any EntityManagerFactory in any configuration (Spring, JPA) or code.

Does hibernate create entityManger objects using default EntityManagerFactory objects?
Or can hibernate directly create EntityManager objects without needing a Factory object?

Comment: are you using spring for Data Access? if so, probably you have some spring configurations in which instantiate a EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

It is injected. Check persistence.xml for persistence unit with name mydatabase. That's the config for this object.

Answer (score 0):

if the question is if the entityManager can be created without any implementation of a Entity Manager Factory from your side then the answer is yes. You just need a persistence-unit named "mydatabase" in your persistence.xml

Comment: is hibernate creats a default EMFactory or it creates without any factory classes.

Comment: here my question is, is entityManager can create without any default/implemented Entity Manager Factory?